# Users with Google's IP address. How is it possible?

Tags: networking, ip

I have a spanish website and I do not allow people from non-european countries to register and to login.

Some time ago I started to receive messages from users who can not login. When I ask for their IP address they tell something like: 66.249.93.202. It's Google's IP adress. How do they get it in their mobile phones? What they have to do to use their real IP address?

Comment: This might become even more common as IPv6 becomes popular, and people use IPv6-to-4 proxies. If you're going to geo-target, do support IPv6 and do not make too many assumptions on the nationality of mobile phones.

Comment: To add to MSalters's comment, don't rely on IPs at all; malicious users will work around it anyway (VPNs, open proxies, etc) and you only end up annoying legitimate users.

Comment: What happens when one of your users from Barcelona travels to Tel Aviv? Will she not be able to log into her account while on business travel?

Comment: if you want to avoid the Google IP address just serve your customers via HTTPS, that will bypass the Data Compression Proxy

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What you're seeing is the Google proxy address.
Mobile users with a chrome browser (either Android or iOS) that have the bandwidth management features turned on will often be seen as using one of these addresses as the requester as [described here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression).

In essence the data you're serving is being requested by the Google Data Compression Proxy, `optimized` and sent back to the end-user.

> What they have to do to use their real IP address.

They shouldn't be doing anything differently.
You can check the `x-forwarded-for` header as explained [in the previously linked documentation.](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression)

Comment: I'm amazed Google is offering a feature that encryption is detrimental to.

Comment: @immibis It's either that, or pulling a [nokia](http://gigaom.com/2013/01/10/nokia-yes-we-decrypt-your-https-data-but-dont-worry-about-it/). You can't optimize what you can't decrypt, and you can't lobby for a https only internet and decrypt it for your own benefit.

Comment: Note that XFF header can be easily spoofed, so there is a solution from wikimedia to check if it's "trusted" XFF header: http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/XFF_project

Answer (score 25):

Probably they are using Google data compression proxy (https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression).

And to answer your question (from the same page):

> As a site owner, how do I perform IP geo-targeting?
>   The IP address
>   of the mobile device is forwarded to the destination server via the
>   X-Forwarded-For header. Site owners should check for this header to
>   correctly determine the location of the user based on client's IP
>   address.

Comment: Seems like we posted nearly simultaneously :D

Comment: @Reaces you were 14 seconds faster :D

Comment: The problem with X-Forwarded-For is that you first need to check the actual IP against a list of trusted proxies before you can trust the header. Else the user can simply send the header themselves and choose any IP they like.

Answer (score 23):

You can get the user's IP address directly if you **simply serve the site over HTTPS**.

**You probably should be doing this anyway** - especially since you mentioned these are login and registration pages.

Quoting from the Data compression Proxy page mentioned in other answers:

> Is my secure traffic optimized by the compression proxy?
>
> No, data
> compression proxy operates on non-encrypted traffic: HTTPS requests
> are sent directly from the mobile device to the destination server.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe these users use Chrome (mobile) with Data Compression Proxy ( https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression )

You can use `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header to geo-locate user based on originial user IP (See FAQ)

Comment: The `X-Forwarded-For` header can easily be spoofed, so it's not safe relying on this header.

Answer (score 1):

I have got same issue. But I didn't get real IP in  `X-Forwarded-For`
I have data saver enabled but X-Forwarded-For index is not set on Header information.
Also I checked HTTP_X_REAL_IP index. It is also set with google IP address.

Finally I found correct IP in index `HTTP_FORWARDED` value as `for=203.192.231.124`

`echo $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']`

So just remove text `for=` from value & you will get IP.

`$ip = str_replace('for=','', $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']);`